# Get outer loop counter while iterating nested for-each loop in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have an XML like the below:

```
<customer>
<fieldgroup>
<field index="1">field1</field>
<field index="2">field1</field>
</fieldgroup>
<fieldgroup>
<field index="1">field3</field>
<field index="2">field4</field>
</fieldgroup>
</customer>
```

The  tag is repeaing and the tag  which is inside it is also repeating. I am using XST 1.0 to transform this to target XML message where I will have to iterate both over  and  like:

```
<xsl for-each select="fieldgroup">
<xsl for-each select="field">
....
</xsl-for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I will have to track which  and  item it is iterating over. In my code which is inside second for-each loop, I can get the loop couner of the  loop but how will I get the loop counter of the parent for-each loop which is iteratin over ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a variable to store the `position()` of the `<fieldgroup>` elements:

```
<xsl:template match="customer">
  <xsl:for-each select="fieldgroup">
    <xsl:variable name="outerIndex" select="position()" />
    <xsl:for-each select="field">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('#outer',$outerIndex,'#inner: ',@index,'#&#xa;')" />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Output is:

```
#outer1#inner: 1#
#outer1#inner: 2#
#outer2#inner: 1#
#outer2#inner: 2#
```

Comment: In XSLT variables can be initialized only once, so will this work? will try and let you know.

Comment: This is correct. But it surely does work. I guess each iteration of the for-loop is considered a new scope with a freshly "created" variable. I did not find anything about this in the [XSLT-1.0 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt11/#variables).

Comment: Yes that's right and it is working, the variable in each iteration of for loop is freshly created. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Anirban It works because `xsl:for-each` is NOT a "loop".

Comment: That's a good perspective. It executes the block _for_ _each_ node (and therefore creates a variable _for_ _each_ block).